# Why doesn't an optional variable raise "Spread types may only be created from object types"?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In the following snippet:

```js
let thing: string | undefined;

const obj = {
  a: 1,
  ...(thing && { b: 2 }),
};

const obj2 = {
  a: 1,
  ...(undefined && { b: 2 }),
};
```

`obj2` raises the TypeScript error: "Spread types may only be created from object types."

Firstly, why doesn't `obj` raise the same if `string` is possibly undefined?

Secondly, why is this error raised at all, because `{...(undefined)}` is in fact valid JavaScript?

Comment: I think this would fall into [_"a concrete difference between doing something that always does nothing and doing something that sometimes does nothing"_](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37491#issuecomment-601733333). TS disallows a lot of things that are in fact valid JavaScript, that's the point of it!

Comment: @AluanHaddad No, it always evaluates to `undefined`, which is the problem. You might be thinking of `undefined || anyExpression`. But I agree it's suspicious in either case

Comment: @Bergi yes indeed

Comment: @jonrsharpe should definitely write an answer pointing to ms/TS#37491 so I can upvote that instead of just doing so on the comment